# Linking issues with pantheios - undefined reference pantheios_init

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, pantheios

I have already read pretty much all of the posts relating to this. I do link to the core library twice, as suggested in so many places. I just can't figure out what the issue is. Here the error:

```
main.o: In function `pantheios_initialiser::pantheios_initialiser()':
/home/awishformore/code/pantheios/include/pantheios/./internal/initialiser.hpp:119: undefined reference to `pantheios_init'
/home/awishformore/code/pantheios/include/pantheios/./internal/initialiser.hpp:121: undefined reference to `pantheios_exitProcess'
main.o: In function `pantheios_initialiser::~pantheios_initialiser()':
/home/awishformore/code/pantheios/include/pantheios/./internal/initialiser.hpp:133: undefined reference to `pantheios_uninit'
```

This is the line my makefile generates for linking:

```
g++ -Wall -g -I/home/awishformore/code/stlsoft/include -I/home/awishformore/code/pantheios/include -I/home/awishformore/code/boost_1_54_0 -I/home/awishformore/code/mysql/include -L/home/awishformore/code/pantheios/lib -L/home/awishformore/code/mysql/lib -L/home/awishformore/code/boost_1_54_0/lib -lpantheios.1.core.gcc46.file64bit.mt -lpantheios.1.fe.simple.gcc46.file64bit.mt -lpantheios.1.be.fprintf.gcc46.file64bit.mt -lpantheios.1.bec.fprintf.gcc46.file64bit.mt -lpantheios.1.core.gcc46.file64bit.mt -lpantheios.1.util.gcc46.file64bit.mt main.o Database.o -o engine
```

I really don't see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours and hours of wasting my time on this, I finally found the answer in this [small, inconspicuous post](http://sourceforge.net/p/pantheios/discussion/647484/thread/06d642e3).

Due to the way pantheios is built and the way gcc works, the libraries need to appear behind the object files in the linking command, as follows:

```
g++ <compiler flags> <include paths> main.o <other objects> <library paths> <libraries> -o main
```

When I tried that, the error changed to undefined pthread references, which was easily solved by linking against the pthread library, too.

Comment: Oh goodness, thanks for this post. I'm glad that I didn't have to go find that small, inconspicuous post, but rather SO hosts your happy answer here!!